# C# wrapper or samples for Google Site Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-custom-search

Anybody seen any c# code examples for using Google site search to send a request to the Google search api and return the results in xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [google-api-for-dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/)